# Why does my class mutator function for a string array cause process returned -1073741819 (0xc0000005)

Tags: c++, arrays, string, mutators

I'm working on a program for a class assignment that reads an input file which details opening chess moves and their stats. Later the program should compare opening moves from "opening.txt" to moves in a sample game "game1.txt" to see if it can detect the opening moves. Well I haven't gotten past trying to read in the input file "opening.txt". The problem I have is setMoves() causes my program to return process returned -1073741819 (0xc0000005). I can't figure out what's wrong between my Opening.h, Opening.cpp, and the call for setMoves() in the ReadOpenings function in main.cpp. The assignment instructions say I have to declare string moves[6] as a private member in the class. Then I need to have accessor and mutator functions. My current code is the only way I don't get compiler errors but it still doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Opening.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int GetNumOpenings();
void CompareOpenings(Opening openings[], int numOpenings);
string DetectOpening(Game *game, Opening opening);
string GetString();
void Menu();
void ReadOpenings(Opening arr[], int size);
void PrintOpenings(Opening arr[], int size);

int main()
{
    Menu();
    return 0;
}

void Menu(){

    int numOpenings = 0;
    numOpenings = GetNumOpenings();
    Opening openings[numOpenings];
    ReadOpenings(openings, numOpenings);

    while(true){
        int action;
        cout<<"Print Stored Openings (1)"<<endl;
        cout<<"Load  Game   File     (2)"<<endl;
        cout<<"Exit                  (0)"<<endl<<endl;

        cout<<"Enter action:";
        cin>>action;
        cin.ignore();
        cout<<endl;
        switch(action){
        case 0:
            cout<<"Exit Selected"<<endl;
            break;
        case 1:
            PrintOpenings(openings, numOpenings);
            break;
        case 2:
            CompareOpenings(openings, numOpenings);
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"Invalid Action"<<endl;

        }
        if(action == 0)
            break;
    }
}

string GetString(){
    string filename;
    cout<<"Please enter game filename:";
    cin>>filename;
    cin.ignore();
    return filename;
}

int GetNumOpenings(){
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("openings.txt");
    int numOpenings;
    infile>>numOpenings;
    infile.close();
    return numOpenings;
}

void CompareOpenings(Opening openings[], int numOpenings){

    //FILL IN
}

string DetectOpening(Game *game, Opening opening){

   //FILL IN
   //remove this return statement
    return " ";
}

void PrintOpenings(Opening arr[], int size){

    //FILL IN
string nameT;
string movesT[6];
string opening_countT;
double wwpT;
double dpT;
double bwpT;

cout<< left << setw(40)<<"NAME"
    << left << setw(30)<<"MOVES"
    << left << setw(30)<<"WIN PERCENTAGES"
    << left << setw(15)<<"TIMES PLAYED" << endl<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
nameT = arr[i].getName();
cout <<left << setw(40)<< nameT;
cout << left <<setw(30)<< arr[i].getMoves();
wwpT = arr[i].getWWP();
cout << wwpT<<",";
dpT = arr[i].getDP();
cout <<dpT<<",";
bwpT = arr[i].getBWP();
cout <<left<< setw(30)<< bwpT;
opening_countT = arr[i].getOpening_Count();
cout<<left << setw(15)<< opening_countT<<endl;
    }
}

void ReadOpenings(Opening arr[], int size){

    //FILL IN
string nameT;
int counter;
string movesT[6] = {"","","","","",""};
string opening_countT;
double wwpT;
double dpT;
double bwpT;

 ifstream infile;
 infile.open("openings.txt");
 infile.ignore(100, '\n');
 for(int i=0; i < 7; i++){
 getline(infile, nameT);

 infile>> counter;
    for(int j=0;j<counter;j++){
    infile>>movesT[j];
        }
 infile>>opening_countT>>wwpT>>dpT>>bwpT;

 arr[i].setName(nameT);
 arr[i].setMoves(movesT);
 arr[i].setOpening_Count(opening_countT);
 arr[i].setWWP(wwpT);
 arr[i].setDP(dpT);
 arr[i].setBWP(bwpT);
 infile.ignore(100, '\n');


    }

infile.close();
}
```

Opening.h

```
#ifndef OPENING_H
#define OPENING_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

class Opening{

    public:
    Opening(); ///constructor



    ///accessor functions
    string getName(){return name;}
    string getMoves(){return moves[6];}
    string getOpening_Count(){return opening_count;}
    double getWWP(){return white_win_percent;}
    double getDP(){return draw_percent;}
    double getBWP(){return black_win_percent;}

    ///mutator functions
    void setName(string nameT){ name = nameT;}
    void setMoves(string movesT[6]){ moves[6] = movesT[6]; }
    void setOpening_Count(string opening_countT){opening_count = opening_countT;}
    void setWWP(double wwpT){white_win_percent = wwpT;}
    void setDP( double dpT){draw_percent = dpT;}
    void setBWP(double bwpT){black_win_percent = bwpT;}


    private:
    string name;
    string moves[6];
    string opening_count;
    double white_win_percent;
    double draw_percent;
    double black_win_percent;



};




#endif // OPENING_H
```

Opening.cpp

```
#include "Opening.h"
#include <iostream>
Opening::Opening(){

 name="";
string moves[6];
opening_count="1";
 white_win_percent = 0;
 draw_percent = 0;
 black_win_percent = 0;

}
```

Openings.txt

```
7
King's Gambit
    3
    e4 e5 f4 
    4055
    31 32 37
Italian Game
    3
    e4 e5 Bc4
    6712
    36 40 24
Bishop's Opening
    4
    e4 e5 Bc4 Nc6
    955
    39 36 26
Ruy Lopez
    5
    e4 e5 Nf3 Nc6 Bb5
    108725
    31 50 20
English Opening Anglo-Dutch Defense
    3
    c4 f5 Kc3
    1021
    37 37 26
Canard Opening
    6
    d4 Nf6 f4 d5 Nf3 Kd7
    1
    0 0 100
Zukertort Opening Sicilian Invitation
    3
    Nf3 c5 c4
    16039
    31 45 23
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: The debugger shows 
#6 0x404e08 Opening::setMoves(this=0x63f8e8, movesT=0x63f7d4)
 as the source of the problem but i'm not sure how this helps me fix my issue. I don't know how to make the function reference the correct address

Comment: Your debugger shows much more than that, and offers you many options for inspecting your program's variable, data, and state, in order to analyze and determine the reason for your program's misbehavior. I would start by inspecting `this` and determining if it looks like a valid object. If not, move up the call stack, in order to determine the reason for the corruption. You'll need to learn debugging skills by yourself, nobody on stackoverflow.com will be able to remotely debug your program for you; only you can do that. Learning how to debug is something all of us had to learn, at some point.

Answer (score 0):

This is a clear error

```
void setMoves(string movesT[6]){ moves[6] = movesT[6]; }
```

`moves` (and `movesT`) are arrays of size 6, so `moves[6]` is an out of bounds array access, resulting in a crash of your program. The legal indexes for `moves` are from 0 to 5 inclusive.

Obviously what you are trying to do is copy the whole array, but you should write a loop to do that (or you could use the `std::copy` function)

```
void setMoves(string movesT[6]) {
    for (int i = 0 i < 6; ++i)
        moves[i] = movesT[i];
}
```

Incidentally you have the same error here

```
string getMoves(){return moves[6];}
```

which is wrong for exactly the same reason.

You should look into using vectors instead of arrays. They are easier and more powerful than arrays. Arrays are rather broken in C++.